# Up and Down buttons for ListView instead of scrollpanel

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm new to javaFX. and I have a question about navigation in ListView, instead of using scrolling bar in the listview for moving up and down, I want to have separated Up and Down buttons for it. But I don't know how to do it, I see somethings with ScaleX and ScaleY but honestly they are not very clear to me. 

Can someone help me? What parameters of the listview should be changed when the up or down button is click ? 

Thank you very much. I'm using javaFX 8.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options.

1. You can use the scrollTo-Method of the listView. There you could use the index and just call the Method with an incremented or decremented one.
2. You can get the scrollbar like this

   ```
   ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) yourListView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
   ```

   and call the setValue-Method to move it with the Buttons.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but i have this exception com.sun.javafx.collections.UnmodifiableListSet cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar , I tried to set ListView to editable but it doesn't help

Comment: I don't know where that comes from?! The code above is working fine at my listView. And the set you get there isn't Unmodifiable but if it doesn't work try too use the normal lookup instead of lookupAll. If that doesn't help then i don't know another solution^^